# c# how to get access to web camera and microphone via a web page (Safari) on iPAD or iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, silverlight, ipad

I am working on a project which is a ASP.NET MVC project. Now I need to implement the functionality which can get access to a web camera and microphone via Safari on iPAD and/or iPhone.
And I do not want to use Flash in this project.

After searching for hours, I found some post which said SilverLight 5 can nicely run on iPAD ([Click here to see the post](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/enterprise-20/silverlight-50-plays-nice-on-the-ipad-009436.php))

But after I tried SilverLight, it is actually not supported on the iOS.

So it seems that Apple have taken any forms of Plug-ins out of its iOS systen.
My questions are:

1. What is the thing that Apple supports on the iPAD or iPhone (iOS) platforms?
2. How did you get access to the web camera via Safari on the iPAD/iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't going to happen. As far as I'm aware there is no way to access the camera via the browser on an iPad.

The only way to do this would be to create a native app which accesses the camera and hands off any pictures to a webview.

Sorry

Comment: Hi, thx to your reply. But you haven't answered the FIRST question.

Comment: And I'm not going to upload pictures. Is it possible to upload video and audio via the way you said？

Comment: Oh sorry, the main programming platform is Objective C + Cocoa Touch (iOS). Get XCode downloaded onto your Mac and you will be able to create iPhone/iPad apps (if you don't have a Mac then you're stuck... unless you can get a virtual machine together). If you create a native app you will be able to upload anything you want to your website. You can send it as data via an api or upload to ftp or something similar. Look into it. :)

Comment: ,Hi Thomas, thank you for your reply. So can I simply understand it in this way that there is no way to get access to a web camera or microphone on a web page on the iPAD?